# is any replacement of ResultSet in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I am using ResultSet for retrieving data from database,but i don't want to use ResultSet. I want to use other Interface for retrieving data.Is any replacement for this?

Comment: Can you let us know what the holdup is with using `ResultSet`?  Maybe you can continue to use it, but in a slightly different way.

Comment: `try{
            String sql = "your query";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs= pst.executeQuery();}catch(SQLException e){}`

Comment: You don't want to use `ResultSet` **why**?

Answer (score 1):

JPA allows you to connect database without  much coding and using stuff like ResultSet. In JPA's persistence.xml file uses driver's name like Mysql(jdbc connector/java) . You have to code least .

See lessons on JPA on this site.

http://www.programming-simplified.com

Answer (score 1):

JDBC has a [RowSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/rowset.html) which extends ResultSet for additioanl functionalities, mayby it will help You. For more details of JDBC features I would suggest [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).